# ms access parse html file for data

Tags: html, ms-access, vba

I have already written the necessary code to parse through a directory and find all of the html files. However I need to parse through each file for necessary information. I need to extract the story title, author, category, number of chapters, source and summary for each story and add them to the correct fields in the database. Each html file is set up the same way. If it is possible I would also like to get a word count for each story too. The word count would be the sum of all of the words in each CHAPTER TEXT area. Below is an outline of how each html file is written. Please let me know the best way to accomplish this.

```
<html>
<head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="author" content="AUTHOR">
    <title>AUTHOR: TITLE</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br/><br/>
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <h1>TITLE</h1>
    </div>
    <b>Story:</b> TITLE<br>
    <b>Storylink:</b> <a href="URL">URL
    <b>Category:</b> CATEGORY<br>
    <b>Author:</b> AUTHOR<br/>
    <b>Last updated:</b> 10/16/2011<br/>
    <b>Status:</b> STATUS<br/>
    <b>Content:</b> Chapter 1 to 16 of 16 chapters<br/>
    <b>Source:</b> SOURCE<br><br>
    <b>Summary:</b> SUMMARY

    <!--CHAPTERAREA START-->
        <h2 class=chapterffdl>*Chapter 1*: Chapter 1</h2>
        CHAPTER TEXT CHAPTER TEXT CHAPTER TEXT

        <h2 class=chapterffdl>*Chapter 2*: Chapter 2</h2>
        CHAPTER TEXT CHAPTER TEXT CHAPTER TEXT

        ...

    <!--CHAPTERAREA STOP-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First off, welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is for specific coding problems or advice only, please post what code you have tried and how it's failing.

Comment: A.M.K,
I am fairly new to access and VBA. I have tried to search for ways to parse a local html file online and was pretty much unsuccessful. The closest I was able to find is parsing through a text file. However I do not know how to read lines from the file. The code I was using as a base is below.


    Dim intFile As String
    Dim strBuffer As String
    Dim strFile As String

    strFile = strPath & strFileName
    intFile = FreeFile()
    Open strFile For Input As #intFile

    Do While EOF(intFile) = False
    Line Input #intFile, strBuffer

    Loop
   
    Close #intFile

Comment: I actually have _no_ experience with access and VBA, I was just reviewing questions, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

A start:

```
Sub ParseHTML()
''Requires that you add a reference to the
''Windows Script Host Object Model
''Use Tools->References

Dim fs As New FileSystemObject
Dim fl As Folder
Dim f As File
Dim ts As TextStream
Dim sList As Variant
Dim rs As Recordset

''s="create table stories (story text,author text,category text,content text,source text,summary text)
''CurrentDb.Execute S

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("stories")

sList = Split("story,author,category,content,source,summary", ",")

Set fl = fs.GetFolder("Z:\docs\")
For Each f In fl.Files
    If f.Type Like "*HTML*" Then
        Debug.Print f.Name
        Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile(f.Path, ForReading)
        Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream
            a = ts.ReadLine
            For i = 0 To UBound(sList)
                If Left(Trim(a), Len(sList(i)) + 4) = "<b>" & sList(i) & ":"
                    If Trim(a) Like "<b>Story:*" Then
                        rs.AddNew
                    End If
                    rs(sList(i)) = Trim(a)
                    If Trim(a) Like "<b>Summary:*" Then
                        rs.Update
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Loop
    End If
Next

End Sub
```